unable to update array without updating other array inside of graalvm
why is this updating two arrays at once when I only updated one?
I tried the spread operator when setting the arrays from the original array.
I tried doing a for loop and populating the array separately.
not sure whats going on.
I didnt see a stack overflow with graalvm and arrays not copying.
chatgpt/claude dont know either
code1:
    s.print("sys_imported_saved_configuration_id: " + sys_imported_saved_configuration_id);
                            const sys_imported_saved_configuration_data = new SysRecord({
                                sys_table_name: 'sys_imported_saved_configuration_data',
                                where: [
                                    [{
                                        "sys_column": "sys_imported_saved_configuration_id",
                                        "sys_operator": "=",
                                        "sys_value": sys_imported_saved_configuration_id
                                    }]
                                ],
                                select_columns: ['sys_id', 'sys_data', 'sys_operation']
                            });

                            const is_data_available = await sys_imported_saved_configuration_data.query();

code2:

class SysRecord {
    constructor({ sys_table_name, select_columns = null, where = null, where_sys_id = null, sort_column = null, sort_direction = null }) {
        this.sys_table_name = sys_table_name;
        this.select_columns = select_columns || [];
        this.where = where || {};
        this.where_sys_id = where_sys_id;
        this.sort_column = sort_column;
        this.sort_direction = sort_direction;
        this.results = [];
        this.currentIndex = -1;
        this.originalResults = []; // To track the original records
    }



    toMap() {
        const queryParams = {};
        if (this.sys_table_name) queryParams['sys_table_name'] = this.sys_table_name;
        if (this.select_columns.length > 0) queryParams['select_columns'] = JSON.stringify(this.select_columns);
        if (Object.keys(this.where).length > 0) queryParams['where'] = JSON.stringify(this.where);
        if (this.where_sys_id) queryParams['where_sys_id'] = this.where_sys_id;
        if (this.sort_column) queryParams['sort_column'] = this.sort_column;
        if (this.sort_direction) queryParams['sort_direction'] = this.sort_direction;
        return queryParams;
    }

    async query() {
        s.print("\n\nquery()");
        // Check and add sys_id and sys_table_name to select_columns if not present
        if (!this.select_columns.includes('sys_id')) {
            this.select_columns.push('sys_id');
        }
        if (!this.select_columns.includes('sys_table_name')) {
            this.select_columns.push('sys_table_name');
        }

        // Execute the query
        const records = await s.get(this.toMap());
        s.print("RECORDS: "+records);

        for( var record of records){
            s.print("record: "+record);

              this.originalResults.push(record);
              this.results.push(record);

        }


//                    this.originalResults = [...records];
//                    this.results = [...records];

        s.print("originalResults: "+this.originalResults);
        s.print("results: "+this.results);


//        this.originalResults = [...records];
//        this.results = [...records];


        this.currentIndex = 0;

        this.set('sys_create',true);


               s.print("\noriginalResults2: "+this.originalResults);
                s.print("results2: "+this.results);


//                    s.print("updated data20: "+this.results[this.currentIndex]);
//                    s.print("originalResults20: "+JSON.stringify(this.originalResults[this.currentIndex]));
//                    s.print("");

        return this.results.length > 0;
    }


    get(fieldName) {
        if (this.currentIndex >= 0 && this.currentIndex < this.results.length) {
            return this.results[this.currentIndex][fieldName];
        }
        return null;
    }

    set(fieldName, value) {
//        s.print("set called with "+fieldName+" :: "+value+ " at index = "+this.currentIndex);
        if (this.currentIndex >= 0 && this.currentIndex < this.results.length) {

            this.results[this.currentIndex][fieldName] = value;
        }
    }

}


Which two arrays are you referring to?

very common issue where newbies don't know that var a = []; var b = a; results in b and a referring to the same array. use .slice for shallow copies, or structuredClone() for a deep clone
